# Undefined name 'arg'

Tags: python, django

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible

class EmployerProfile(AbstractAddress):
    customer = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomerProfile, verbose_name=_('Customer'),
        related_name='employerprofile')

    company_name = models.CharField(_('Company name'),
                                    max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = PhoneField(_('Phone'), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_extension = models.CharField(_('Extension'), max_length=10,
                                       blank=True, null=True)
    job_title = models.CharField(_('Job title'), max_length=50, blank=True,
                                 null=True)
    date_hired = models.DateField(_('Date hired'), blank=True, null=True)
    supervisor_name = models.CharField(_('Supervisor name'), max_length=50,

...
                                       blank=True, null=True)
    has_missing_fields = models.BooleanField(_('Has missing informations'),
                                             default=True)
    manual_validation = GenericRelation(ManualFieldValidation)
```

Here is a function I would like to modify in using a metaclass

```
def clean_fields(self):
        if income_source != 'Employed':
            to_empty = [
                "company_name",
                "job_title",
                "date_hired",
                "supervisor_name",
                "phone",
                "phone_extension",
                "civic_number",
                "street",
                "address_line_2",
                "city",
                "state",
                "zip_code",
                ...
            ]
            for field_name in to_empty:
                setattr(self, field_name, None)
        super(EmployerProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Could anyone be able to tell why I have this type of error for the line `super(EmployerProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`? I took few time to figure out what was the problem, but without success.

Comment: you are calling the `save` methods'  super in `clean_fields` - get rid of that line altogether. You dont need it.

Comment: @karthikr Why are you saying that?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error for the reason given: the name `args` is not defined either in the global or local scope.  Neither is kwargs.